# Spring - Preventing the execution of parallel transactions on multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, transactions

I have three tables T1,T2,T3 and four transactions (A,B,C,D) that perform the following actions (this is not very important for my question - in the future, there may be more tables):

A - T1, T2 - read, T1, T2, T3 - write
B - T1, T2, T3 read/write
C, D - T1 - read, T3 read/write.

I don't have a performance requirements, so I decided to prevent concurrent transactions:

1. I created a table `transactionlock` with one row.
2. I created JPA Interface:

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface TransactionLockRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionLock, Long> {

     @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
     @Query("select t from TransactionLock t")
     TransactionLock lock();

   }
   ```
3. I call `lock()` at the beginning of each transaction

   ```
   @Autowired
   private TransactionLockRepository lock;

   @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
   @Override
   public void transactionOne() {
     lock.lock();
     //my business code ...  
   }

   @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
   @Override
   public void transactionTwo() {
     lock.lock();
     //my business code ...  
   }
   ```

The program seems to work correctly, but I'm not sure that my implementation is absolutely correct and does not contain errors.

**UPDATED**

If I try to synchronize transactions without an additional table, then I have the following problem:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) 
public void businessLogic() {
  List<TableOne> data1 = tableOneRepository.findAll();
  sleep(300);
  List<TableTwo> data2 = tableTwoRepository.findAll();
  ... Some insert/delete/update queries for tableOne, tableTwo
}


@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) 
public void cleanEvent() {
  tableOneRepository.deleteAll();
  tableOneRepository.flush();
  tableTwoRepository.deleteAll();
  tableTwoRepository.flush();
}


public void execute() {
  transactions.businessLogic();
}

// In other thread
public void execute2() {
  sleep(100);
  transactions.cleanEvent();
}
```

I want the first transaction to be performed first, but in this case i have:

0) Transaction 1 - start

1) Transaction 1 - reading table one

2) Transaction 1 - sleep 300

3) Transaction 2 - start

4) Transaction 2 - deleting table two (I don't want it!)

5) Transaction 2 - deleting table one

6) Transaction 1 - deadlock (cant read table two)

Can I solve this problem without an additional table?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for a code review. Consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (but check their rules and expectations first!)

Comment: Sorry! word 'review' - wrong in this case. I just asked about the right way for preventing the execution of parallel transactions on multiple tables

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? That is what a database is for... Use the proper isolation level instead (`SERIALIZABLE`) instead of trying to write your own.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my initial question - added a sample code.